# Silverlight clientaccesspolicy.xml bug? or design?

Tags: silverlight, clientaccesspolicy.xml

In the domain node of a clientaccesspolicy file you can specify a wildcard for a sub domain or protocol, but it would appear not for a port.

Specifically when developing, if the service consumed is hosted on a third party, then access from a local debug version of a silverlight app running on the localhost asp.net development server works fine with the nodes:

```
<domain uri="*"/>
<domain uri="http://*"/>
<domain uri="http://localhost:1234"/>
```

(where 1234 is the specific determined port number)

but it would appear not to work if specified in the form

```
<domain uri="http://localhost:*"/>
```

which is extremely annoying if there are multiple developers/projects using the service or you do not specify a port for the asp.net development server

Does annyone know if I am simply getting the format incorrect or is this either a bug or an oversight in the handling of the clientaccesspolicy by silverlight?

Answer (score 6):

The behavior you describe is in line with the documentation, which states:

> There are three types of wildcards
>   allowed:
>
> A standalone '*' wildcard. This option
>   is used to allow access to all domains
>   of the same scheme. An HTTP service
>   will allow all HTTP callers. An HTTPS
>   service will allow all HTTPS callers.
>
> An "http://*" literal wildcard. This
>   option explicitly allows all HTTP
>   callers, even if this is an HTTPS
>   service.
>
> A subdomain wildcard. This option uses
>   a wildcard at the first segment of the
>   path ("http://*.contoso.com", for
>   example) that allows all subdomains of
>   the domain specified. So for the
>   example. http://web.contoso.com and
>   http://mail.contoso.com would be
>   allowed. Note that a uri path where
>   the wildcard does not occur as a
>   prefix (http://web.*.com, for example)
>   is disallowed.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx

So there's nothing about wildcards for ports, which (you're right) does not make any sense when you allow wildcards for hosts and domains.

Answer (score 3):

Work-around:

Under **Properties** of your website hosting the SL app, go to the **Web** tab, and change the Auto-assign Port to **Specific Port**.  This way, you can set your localhost:1234 port in the clientaccesspolicy file as you already illustrated, and expect it not to need a port change no matter what developers also then use the project.

This is not a perfect solution, as its always nicer to auto assign rather than hard set ports in projects.  Buts its a good option to try.